# Javascript setTimeout/clearTimeout weird behavior in electron

Tags: javascript, timeout, settimeout, electron

I'm building and electron app that loads a page and conduct some test on a page once the page is loaded. I want to enforce a timeout on the page load, so let's say after 5 seconds if page doesn't load, move onto the next item.

My code is something like this in my main process:

```
var timer;
var urls = [...];

var win = new BrowserWindow({...});
var myURL = "";

var setTimer = function (){
    timer = setTimeout(()=>{
        console.log(myURL + " timed out");
        loadNext();
    }, 5000);
}

var loadNext = function(){
    if (urls.length > 0){
        timer = setTimer();
        myURL = urls.pop();
        console.log(myURL);
        win.loadURL(myURL;
    }   
}

win.webContent.on('did-finish-load', () => {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    browserWindow.webContents.send('doTest');
})

ipcMain.on('testResult', (event, data) => {
    console.log('done test ' + data);
    event.returnValue = 'yay';
})
```

And in my render process, there's a listener that listens to 'doTest' and will send back a message synchronously.

For the most part, this code work: when the page didn't finish load after 5s, it moves onto the next URL and output correct message like this:

```
url1
url1 timed out
url2 
done test url2
url3
url3 timed out 
...
```

However, occasionally, it gives out output like this:

```
urla
urla timed out
urlb
done test urla
done test urlb
urlc
done test urlc
```

I expected the `clearTimeout` would remove the timeout function before I send out the request to conduct test, so the `done test urla` should never happen after `urla timed out` output. What's going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your timer variable is undefined.

```
var timer;
    var urls = [...];

    var win = new BrowserWindow({...});
    var myURL = "";

    var setTimer = function (){
        //Missing return statement
        timer = setTimeout(()=>{
            console.log(myURL + " timed out");
            loadNext();
        }, 5000);
    }

    var loadNext = function(){
        if (urls.length > 0){
            //Following line sets timer to undefined:
            //timer = setTimer(); (comment it out)
            //change to:
            setTimer();
            myURL = urls.pop();
            console.log(myURL);
            win.loadURL(myURL; //Also don't forget to fix this)
        }   
    }

    win.webContent.on('did-finish-load', () => {
        clearTimeout(timer);
        browserWindow.webContents.send('doTest');
    })

    ipcMain.on('testResult', (event, data) => {
        console.log('done test ' + data);
        event.returnValue = 'yay';
    })
```